# Python type checking: cannot assign to a dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, typechecking

I get the following error message in my Python code when assigning something to a dict:

```
Argument of type "dict[Unknown, Unknown]" cannot be assigned to parameter "__value" of type "str" in function "__setitem__"
  "dict[Unknown, Unknown]" is incompatible with "str"
```

The code:

```py
async def notify(self, method: str, params: Optional[dict] = None):
    reqDict = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": method}
    if params is not None:
        reqDict["params"] = params
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ error
```

I don't understand why that is. The following code works fine:

```py
async def notify(self, method: str, params: Optional[dict] = None):
    id = 1
    reqDict = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": id, "method": method}
    if params is not None:
        reqDict["params"] = params
```

Not much difference, just the extra "id" key in the dict.

What is wrong here? My code or the type checker? How can I fix this?

This appears in VSCode 1.74.1 on Windows 10 with the Python extension and Python 3.9.6.

Comment: `reqDict` is being inferred as a dictionary where the keys and values are strings, `dict[str, str]`. If you have a key where the value _isn't_ a string, like `id`, the inferred type is necessarily broader. If the inferred type isn't what you want, give an explicit one like `dict[str, Any]`.

Comment: What is `method`? You must provide a [mcve]. The problem is the type  that the dictionary is.being inferred to have, so probably you can type annotate that dictionary correctly, possibly with a `TypedDict` if the keys don't change and are of different types

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sounds plausible, but how do I do that? `reqDict: dict = {"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": method}` changes nothing.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This should be reproducible already. `method` is `str` as can be seen in the function paramters.

Comment: It fixes it for MyPy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=b30b6a1ebfa6cc9cfc2c2297d32cf916. Note `dict` is a generic type, you can be more specific.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Seen your edit now. `dict[str, Any]` helps. Thank you! If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: @ygoe, just because the type is annotated `str` doesn't mean the value passed is actually a `str`. I think this is what @juanpa.arrivillaga was getting at.